# Improve Walk Froward Speed

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for guidance (beginner level) on how to speed up this code?

X is a 7000x20 array

```
X = X.values
n_train = 500
n_records = len(X)
regime = []
for i in range(n_train, n_records):
    train_model = GaussianHMM(n_components = 3, random_state = 100,
                                covariance_type = "diag").fit(X[0:i])
    predict_model = train_model.predict(X[i:i+1])
    regime.append(predict_model)
```

Comment: There is not much we cen speed up here. What does `GaussianHMM` and `train_model.predict` do?

Comment: Maybe cast X to a `pandas.DataFrame` and use [`.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html)

Comment: Thanks usaer_na. GaussianHMM estimates a Markov Model and predict is the out-of-sample prediction. Was thinking if parallelisation would help, but I have literally zero experience with that.

Comment: thanks @not_speshal. I am trying with pd.rolling instead to make it consistent with the code I posted.